How to declare an environment variable in a step using Bash in Harness and use it as a condition in a subsequent step
I'm working on a CI/CD pipeline in Harness and need help with declaring an environment variable in one step using Bash, then using its value as a condition in a following step.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
In the first step, I want to declare an environment variable with a value that could be true or false based on certain conditions.
In the second step, I need to check this variable’s value and only proceed if it is false.
How can I set this up in Harness? Any examples or best practices would be really helpful.

Define a stage variable, pass your environment variable to that stage variable. In subsequent steps you can refer the value of the stage variable.
